# API returning character entities in JSON

Tags: support, api

I noticed display names in the JSON contain HTML character entities; e.g.
[/2.0/users/718618?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=718618&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Gives me:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "user_id": 718618,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "creation_date": 1303376809,
      "display_name": "C&#233;dric Julien",
...
```

I can HtmlDecode the display names I'm getting from the API. Would it be better if the API just returned the UTF8 character?

Relevant SO question: [JSON character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583562/json-character-encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) is unsafe=false, so the strings are coming back escaped. If I create a filter with unsafe=true the names come thru without the escaping.